# Typescript unable to resolve property on the union type

Tags: typescript, types

It looks I don't know some ts specific compilation issues.

I've these interfaces:

```
export interface CommonSearchQuery {
  text: string;
  category: number;
}

export type SearchBrandQuery = CommonSearchQuery & {
  availability: string;
}

export type SearchLocationQuery = CommonSearchQuery & {
  zip: string;
}

export type SearchQuery = SearchLocationQuery | SearchBrandQuery;
```

And my usage

```
export const fetchBrands = (params: SearchQuery, type: RequestType): Promise<any> => {
   console.log(params.availability);
}
```

I got this error

```
TS2339: Property 'availability' does not exist on type 'SearchQuery'.
  Property 'availability' does not exist on type 'SearchLocationQuery'.
```

My ts config

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "incremental": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "ES2017"],
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "./dist/*",
    "./node_modules/*",
    "./stories/*"
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Only `SearchBrandQuery` has availability, did you mean -> `export type SearchQuery = SearchLocationQuery & SearchBrandQuery;` instead?

Answer (score 2):

Because you're using a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types), `params` will be **either** a `SearchLocationQuery` **or** a `SearchBrandQuery`. Only `SearchBrandQuery` has `availability`, `SearchLocationQuery` doesn't. So before you can use `params.availability`, you have to *narrow* the type of `params` so you know that it has that property.

One way you do that with type guards. For instance, this has no error:

```
export const fetchBrands = (params: SearchQuery, type: RequestType): Promise<any> => {
    if ("availability" in params) {
        console.log(params.availability);
    }
    // ...
}
```

...because by the time you try to use `availability`, the guard has demonstrated that you're dealing with a `SearchBrandQuery`, so the TypeScript compiler can narrow the type.

---

Alternatively, you could use an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) which would have **all** of the properties:

```
export type SearchQuery = SearchLocationQuery & SearchBrandQuery;
```

The problem is that then `params` has to have all the properties even if you don't need them for the kind of search you're doing. I get the impression you don't want to do that (probably for that reason), since you use intersection types elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is flawed. `SearchQuery` is either `SearchLocationQuery` OR `SearchBrandQuery`. One of them has the property `availability`. So the compiler will complain that `availability` is not a union of both types which will lead to the error

```
TS2339: Property 'availability' does not exist on type 'SearchQuery'.
 Property 'availability' does not exist on type 'SearchLocationQuery'.
```

So you have to check for their type e.g. with the `in` operator e.g.

```
export const fetchBrands = (params: SearchQuery, type: RequestType): Promise<any> => {
  if ("availability" in params) {
     console.log(params.availability); // works fine
  }
}
```